# graphs on surfaces

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, topological-graph-theory

I'm looking for references on embedding graphs in surfaces (motivation:  I was doodling and wondered how many distinct embeddings of $K_{3,3}$ into the torus there are.)

Answer (score 3):

Lando S.K., Zvonkin A.K. — Graphs on Surfaces and Their Applications

Answer (score 3):

See the wikipedia article on [topological graph theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_graph_theory) and the book *Topological graph theory* by Gross and Tucker.

Answer (score 0):

J.A. Bondy and U.S.R.Murty, *Graph Theory with Applications*.

Jonathan Gross and Thomas Tucker, *Topological Graph Theory*